# How to implement \text in plain tex?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

I am trying to implement the LaTeX command `\text{}` which makes texts in math mode behave as if outside math mode.

My current attempt is as follows.

```
\def\text#1{\begingroup\rm\testing#1\endtest}
{\escapechar=-1\xdef\endtest{\string\\endtest}}
\def\testing#1#2{\ifx#2\endtest\let\next=\endgroup\else\let\next=\testing\fi%
{\catcode`\|=10\ifcat#1|\hskip.5em\else#1\fi}\next #2}
```

### This has at least 2 drawbacks: First, it produces a `\endtest` after the text; second, there are no spaces in the texts.

For example,

```
\text{example haha}
```

gives

```
examplehaha\endtest.
```

I am running out of ideas to get rid of the `\endtest` and produce a space in the texts.

---

Any help or reference is highly appreciated by a newbie like me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you copy the definition of `\text`? I think it's some sort of `\hbox` inside `\mathchoice`.

Comment: For reference, the definition is found in `amstext.sty`. (`kpsewhich amstext.sty` will tell you where it is.)

Comment: There is `\hbox{...}` for text, which can be used inside math. And `\mathchoice` helps, when you want to have different font sizes depending on the current math style.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks, but I don't see how I am going to implement that implementation, without LaTeX. I don't understand how it works either...

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks for informing me of this use of `\hbox` and the interesting control sequence `\mathchoice`. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Really in plain you just have to use

```
\hbox{hello world}
```

in `amsmath` (or more exactly `amstext`) `\text` is defined to use `\mathchoice` and use different size text is subscripts etc, however plain tex has no real font size changing commands so there is, by default, nothing comparable you can do.
If you restrict to `\rm` then that font is set up at different sizes in `\fam0` so you could do

```
\def\textrm#1{\mathchoice
{\hbox{\the\textfont0 #1}}
{\hbox{\the\textfont0 #1}}
{\hbox{\the\scriptfont0 #1}}
{\hbox{\the\scriptscriptfont0 #1}}}


$$\textrm{one two} x^{\textrm{one two}^{\textrm{one two}}}$$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for daunting me on the use of `\hbox`. It really saved my day. :)

Answer (score 16):

You can use `opmac` (which I recommend anyway if you insist in using plain TeX):

```
\input opmac

\def\text#1{%
  \relax
  \ifmmode
    \mathchoice
      {\hbox{#1}}
      {\hbox{#1}}
      {\hbox{\typoscale[700/]\relax#1}}
      {\hbox{\typoscale[500/]\relax#1}}%
  \else
    \hbox{#1}%
  \fi
}
$$
a\text{a}_{a\text{a}_{a\text{a}}}
$$
$$
a+b=b+a\text{ is a {\it nice\/} property}
$$
$$
\scriptstyle a+b=b+a\text{ is a {\it nice\/} property}
$$
$$
\scriptscriptstyle a+b=b+a\text{ is a {\it nice\/} property}
$$

\bye
```

[image]

---

Just for the fun of it, let me try describing what your macros do.

```
\def\text#1{\begingroup\rm\testing#1\endtest}
{\escapechar=-1\xdef\endtest{\string\\endtest}}
\def\testing#1#2{\ifx#2\endtest\let\next=\endgroup\else\let\next=\testing\fi%
{\catcode`\|=10\ifcat#1|\hskip.5em\else#1\fi}\next #2}
```

First `\text` is defined to absorb its argument and return the token list

```
\begingroup\rm\testing<argument>\endtesting
```

The macro `\testing` is defined to have two arguments. If the second argument is `\endtest`, the control sequence `\next` is defined to be `\endgroup` else it is defined to be `\testing`, which starts up a recursion. Then

```
{\catcode`\|=10\ifcat#1|\hskip.5em\else#1\fi}
```

is done, where `#1` stands for the first token (or contents of braced group) following `\testing`. The test `\ifcat#1|` will *not* succeed if `#1` is a space for two reasons: spaces are ignored when TeX is looking for an undelimited argument, so `#1` will *never* be a space token; second reason, the test will succeed when `#1` is a single token of category code 12, which is the category code of `|` at definition's time.

Thus you get a space when a character such as `.` (catcode 12) follows (and the character is ignored), or the character otherwise, if it is a letter. If `#1` is the contents of a braced group, then, well, anything can happen. Finally `\next` is executed, and `#2` is reinserted. This is the reason for “endtest” to appear at the end.

Recall that when an argument is absorbed, category codes are frozen, so the setting `` \catcode`\|=10 `` does nothing at all.

A recursion without the “termination” problem is obtained by adding two terminators.

```
% generic terminators
\def\TerminatorA{\TerminatorA}
\def\TerminatorB{\TerminatorB}

\def\boldenas#1{\boldenasRecurse#1\TerminatorA\TerminatorB}
\def\boldenasRecurse#1#2#3\TerminatorB{%
  \boldenasDo{#1}%
  \ifx#2\TerminatorA
    \let\next\boldenasEnd
  \else
    \let\next\boldenasRecurse
  \fi
  \next#2#3\TerminatorB
}
\def\boldenasDo#1{%
  \ifx #1a%
    {\bf a}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\def\boldenasEnd#1\TerminatorB{}


\boldenas{abracadabra}

\bye
```

This is not safe against `#1` being empty (we're tough plain TeX users, after all). Spaces will be gobbled for the reason I explained earlier and braced groups will produce chaos. But, hey, we're doing theory!

Note that the `\let` instructions can be avoided:

```
% generic terminators
\def\TerminatorA{\TerminatorA}
\def\TerminatorB{\TerminatorB}
% syntactic sugar
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}

\def\boldenas#1{\boldenasRecurse#1\TerminatorA\TerminatorB}
\def\boldenasRecurse#1#2#3\TerminatorB{%
  \boldenasDo{#1}%
  \ifx#2\TerminatorA
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \fi
  \boldenasEnd\boldenasRecurse#2#3\TerminatorB
}
\def\boldenasDo#1{%
  \ifx #1a%
    {\bf a}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\def\boldenasEnd#1\TerminatorB{}


\boldenas{abracadabra}

\bye
```

Comment: The leading space is trimmed in the script styles. Is this intended?

Comment: why is there no space between `$a$` and "is" in either of the "script" styles?

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's a good question!  But it should be addressed to Petr. `;-)` Fixed.

Comment: @Guido Apparently, `\typosize` is looking ahead and so it gobbles the space. Fixed.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the explanation: I am wondering if there is a technique to get rid of that `\endtest` string while still able to have recursion: maybe I shall `\let\next=` some other macro to absorb that ending sequence? Also, it seems I have no way to absorb spaces in the argument of a macro? Finally, thanks a lot for the recommendation of `opmac`, it is quite a nice thing to know. :-D

Comment: @awllower The simplest technique is to define `\testing` with three arguments, adding a further token after `\endtest`; I'll add an example.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for this useful example: I wish I could up vote twice :P